# C++ stack vs heap allocation

Tags: c++, memory-management

I was wondering when should I allocate a class on the stack in C++? I have a strong background in Java and in Java all classes are allocated on the heap, using the `new` keyword. In C++ I can pick between stack and heap allocation but now that smart pointers are introduced, it makes more sense to allocate everything that doesn't transfer ownership with `std::unique_ptr`.

I can't really think of any cases, where it would be necessary or better to use stack allocation. Maybe for some kind of optimisation in embedded systems?

Comment: Just an FYI a `std::unique_ptr` is a "stack" based object.  BTW we call then automatic and dynamic objects as C++ has no concept of stack or heap.  IMHO you want to use automatic objects whenever possible,

Comment: You normally use the opposite principle: if dynamic allocation isn't necessary, you don't do it. Dynamic allocation by default is "premature pessimisation".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use automatic (stack) allocation whenever the function scope - or the scope of a control block such as a `for`, `while`, `if` etc. inside the function - is a good match for the lifetime the object needs.  That way, if the object owns/controls any resources, such as dynamically allocated memory, file handles etc. - they will be freed during the destructor call as that scope is left.  (Not at some unpredictable later time when a garbage collector winds up).

Only use `new` if there's a clear need, such as:

- needing the object to live longer than the function scope,
- to hand over ownership to some other code
- to have a container of pointers to base classes that you can then process polymorphically (i.e. using virtual dispatch to derived-class function implementations), or
- an especially large allocation that would eat up much of the stack (your OS/process will have "negotiated" a limit, usually in the 1-8+ megabyte range)

  - if this is the only reason you're using dynamic allocation, and you do want the lifetime of the object tied to a scope in your function, you should use a local `std::unique_ptr<>` to manage the dynamic memory, and ensure it is released no matter how you leave the scope: by `return`, `throw`, `break` etc..  (You may also use a `std::unique_ptr<>` data member in a `class`/`struct` to manage any memory the object owns.)

Mathieu Van Nevel comments below about C++11 move semantics - the relevance is that if you have a small management object on the stack that controls a large amount of dynamically allocated (heap) memory, move semantics grant extra assurances and fine-grained control of when the management object hands over its resources to another management object owned by other code (often the caller, but potentially some other container/register of objects).  This handover can avoid data on the heap being copied/duplicated even momentarily.  Additionally, *elision* and *return-value-optimisation* often allow nominally automatic/stack-hosted variables to be constructed directly in some memory they're eventually being assigned/returned-to, rather than copied there later.

Comment: that's a good summary. I recently reworked some code that was putting an array of very large objects in the stack. If you're not careful, you can run out of stack space in a larger program or one with deep recursion.

Comment: Some details about c++11 move semantic, and the answer will be perfect i think : upvote

Comment: Good summary, if you add when should I use std::unique_ptr instead of stack allocation I will give you the answer tick.

Comment: Didn't want to sound rude, I'm just always like this.

Answer (score 1):

In large codebase we use stack allocation for simple struct objects while for more complex classes(that involve polymorphism, memory ownership etc) we always use dynamic allocation.