# Is the use of "new" necessary when creating a pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I did exactly this on a different computer and got a segmentation fault error:

```
int * ptr_to_int;
*ptr_to_int = 34;
cout << *ptr_to_int << endl;
```

However, I'm doing it now on my computer and it works just fine. What could be the reason for this?

My main question is: is it strictly necessary to use the "new" operator to reserve memory for this pointer? As in:

```
int * ptr_to_int = new int;
*ptr_to_int = 34;
cout << *ptr_to_int << endl;
```

I know "new" must be used when using pointers to structures. Is it also necessary with basic types?

Comment: You may also do `int my_var; int* ptr = &my_var;` without `new`.

Comment: This is a combined duplicate of the linked Question and [C++ stack vs heap allocation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36646493/514235).

Comment: @iammilind, what a woderful dupe you've found!